# Show that the sample variance is an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ for the Poisson distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, variance, parameter-estimation

I am trying to show that the sample variance is an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ for a Poisson distribution.

Let $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be a random sample from a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda > 0$.

The sample variance is given as

$$S^2 = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n-1}$$

For $S^2$ to be an unbiased estimator, I need to show that $\mathbb{E}[S^2] = \lambda$

My attempt:

I know that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = \lambda$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i} \sim \text{Poisson}(n\lambda)$

Using linearity of expectations as [in this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363697/for-a-poisson-model-show-that-the-sample-mean-overline-x-is-an-unbiased-esti):

$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[S^2] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n-1} \right] \\ 
    &= \dfrac{1}{n-1}\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( {X_{i}}^{2} + {\bar{X}}^2 - 2X_i\bar{X} \right)  \right] \\
    &= \dfrac{1}{n-1} \left( n \lambda^2 + \lambda^2 - 2\lambda^2 \right) \\
    &= \dfrac{1}{n-1}(n + 1 -2) \lambda^2 \\
    &= \dfrac{1}{n-1} (n-1) \lambda^2 \\
    &= \lambda^2
\end{align*}
$$

I end up with $\lambda^2$ but I need to end up with $\lambda$ to show that $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Using your approach, you should have

\begin{align}
&E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2+\bar X^2-2X_i\bar X)\right]
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i^2)-nE(\bar X^2)
\\&=n(\lambda+\lambda^2)-n\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}+\lambda^2\right)
\\&=n\lambda-\lambda
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1701626/321264

Comment: Maybe it won't hurt to remember that the variance of a Poisson distribution is the same as its expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked where you went wrong. There are several mistakes you made. Firstly,

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} {X_{i}}^{2} \right] 
    \ne  n \lambda^2 
$$

Handled correctly,

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} {X_{i}}^{2} \right] 
    =  n \mathbb{E}[X^2] = n\left(\mathbb{V}[X]+\mathbb{E}[X]^2\right)=n\lambda+n\lambda^2
$$

Also you incorrectly did this evaluation:

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( {\bar{X}}^2 - 2X_i\bar{X} \right)  \right]
    \ne \left(\lambda^2 - 2\lambda^2 \right)
$$

The correct evaluation is:

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( {\bar{X}}^2 - 2X_i\bar{X} \right)  \right]
=-n\mathbb{E} \left[ {\bar{X}}^2  \right]
    = -\lambda - n\lambda^2
$$
since
$$
\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}^2] = \left(\mathbb{V}[\bar{X}]+\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]^2\right)=\lambda/n+\lambda^2
$$

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, I realise where I went wrong now.

Comment: When I tried this, summing together $n\lambda + n\lambda^{2} + (n\lambda^{2} - 2n\lambda^{2}) = n\lambda$. Then multiplying by $\frac{1}{n-1}$ still doesn't get me to $\lambda$. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, corrected a mistake above.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now, much appreciated.